# WordPress site malware attack. My WordPress site shows a white blank page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

I am updated my *primary* domain WordPress version from 4.7 to 4.8. After this, all of my Addon Domains are not live and are showing white blank pages.

I also got a mail from [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy) that your primary domain has a malware attack, so please scan and remove it. But I am confused about how to scan my primary domain in the GoDaddy [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) interface and remove malware, so that all my addon domain will be live.

I have also do not have access to all addon domains on WordPress Admin page either. Only the primary domain is live and access WordPress dashboard. If there a solution to solve this issue, please submit it here and help me to solve it perfectly.

Comment: Did you use nulled theme ?

Comment: no...I have Premium Paid theme.

Comment: 1. take that site offline NOW. 2. delete all php files (they are infected anyway) 3. check your backups of database content and file storage content (which you HOPEFULLY dump on a regular base). 4. install those into  a fresh instance on your _development_ system and if that works fine then 5 upload all of that o your live site.

Comment: 1) Install a new copy of wordpress 2) upload theme 3) set wp_config to point your old database. 4) Download some malware plugins. and most importantly don't install any nulled plugin.

Comment: @SaadSuri  How to Backup individual Addon Domains in cpanel....When using Backup wizard in cpanel it backed holl or full backup.

Comment: Don't go for a backup of files as they all are hacked.

Comment: you can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/ plugin) to check infected files on WordPress setup!

Comment: @AnkitaTanti  I have only access to Primary domain WordPress Dashboard, so the plugin I install in primary domain to check malware and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Install the WordPress plugin *[Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/)*, activate it, then register an account, generate an API key, update the malware database definitions and then run a full scan.

This will detect quite a lot of malicious files and malware and provide you with a list with all the infected files. I suggest you manually review each of the files and see if they actually are malware or contain just a bunch of malware code somewhere inside.

Download the latest WordPress version from the official WordPress site:
https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz

Extract all the files on your computer and then upload them via FTP on your [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) account in the *public_html* folder and overwrite the current WordPress files. You basically need to upload the *wp-admin* folder, *wp-includes* folder and *wp-content* folders and the other wp-*.php files (be careful not to overwrite your *wp-config.php*) file.

Check if after removing the malware and re-uploading the WordPress files from an unaltered WordPress archive makes your site functional again.

Comment: Why would we trust that WordPress plugin?

Comment: Re *"overwrite the current WordPress files"*: Why not make a backup first? E.g., forensics may be impossible if they are overwritten.